# Using const getter-style functions in place of static data members

Tags: c++, static, constants, getter

A very simple thought that got me wondering: is there anything to be gained from using the following in a class:

```
static const int maximum_hp{10};
```

Rather than

```
int maximum_hp() const{return 10;};
```

...?

As far as I can see, the first way makes it easier to override the value of maximum_hp if needed in child classes (by declaring it virtual, of course); static data members cannot be modified, however. For constant primitive types, it seems, to me, to be a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one thing which the static member gives you that the function does not: if the value is present in the class definition like you've shown, it can be used as a *constant expression* (such as an array bound or a template argument). In other words, this is legal:

```
std::array<int, Class::maximum_hp_static_memer> a;
```

while this is not:

```
std::array<int, c.maximum_hp_function()> a;
```

Comment: Just to mention that *if* the function would be *constexpr*, the second example would be fine